# Epub Fixed Layout is not full screen in Portrait

Tags: svg, epub3

I have an epub 3 ebook I have uploaded for Google Play(but is not live). It is a Fixed layout Epub. To create the book, I have used images as the entire page.
 Each page of the book is a file that links to the image. 
When viewing the book on any device, when in portrait the image/page is in the top-left corner and only fills 2/3 of the screen.    I want it to fill the entire screen, with respect the picture’s ratio. I thought I had corrected this problem with SVG for the image, instructing it with

> svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1800" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1276 1800" width="1276" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
>   And
>   meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" /> in the Head>.

It is pre-paignated with landscape as a spread.
Is there something I am obviously doing wrong?, because I am entirely new to this game. I started coding very recently and plan to learn it in-depth but I really need this project finished soon, so any help from someone who knows about epub 3 would be amazing! Please, and thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You have declare the metadata in OPF File Following Code:

```
<meta property="rendition:orientation">auto</meta>
```

Add the head element for each html page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1700 height=1082"></meta>
```

I hope this is help for you...